# Changing values in polymorphic boost::shared_ptr (inside std::vector)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, vector, stdvector

I have the following base calibration struct:

```
struct Standard
{
public:
    unsigned long ulCamID;
    std::string sCalibrationModel;
    float fC;
    float fXh;
    float fYh;
    Standard()
    {
        ulCamID = 0;
        fC = fXh = fYh = 0.0;
    }
    virtual ~Standard()
    {

    }
};
```

And derived structs such as:

```
struct Aus: public Standard
{
public:
    float fK1;
    float fK2;
    float fK3;
    float fP1;
    float fP2;
    float fB1;
    float fB2;
    Aus()
    {
        fC = fXh = fYh = fK1 = fK2 = fK3 = fP1 = fP2 = fB1 = fB2 = 0.0;
    }
};
```

Because I do not know at compile how many Calibrations I will need, nor which calibration models, I thought it convenient to put it into a std::vector and use boost::shared_ptr to point to them. I do this like so:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<CalibrationModels::Standard> shr_ptr;
std::vector<shr_ptr> vec;
shr_ptr p(new CalibrationModels::Aus);
vec.push_back(p);
p.reset(new CalibrationModels::Brown);
vec.push_back(p);
```

This seems to work fine (the debugger reports that the pointers inside the vector point to the derived struct). However, I have difficulties now to access/change the values inside the vector. If I try something like this:

```
boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<CalibrationModels::Aus>(vec.at(0)).px->fK3 = 1.3221e-9
```

It tells me that px is private ( ‘boost::shared_ptr::element_type* boost::shared_ptr::px’ is private element_type * px; ).

What is the proper way to access and manipulate the values inside those pointers to derived structs?

Comment: Try:   
boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<CalibrationModels::Aus>(vec.at(0))->fK3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that `px` is a private member of the smart pointer. To access your class boost provides the `->` operator. You can use that to access the pointer as you would use it for a regular pointer. This would change your line to this:

```
boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<CalibrationModels::Aus>(vec.at(0))->fK3 = 1.3221e-9;
                                                              ^^ Difference here
```

Note that, if you actually need the value, you can use the `get()` method to get the pointer that is stored in the `shared_ptr`.